# Prove that a function has 2 solution and find one solution using the bisection method

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

$ln(x^2+2x+\frac{1}{2})=x$

Prove that this equation has 2 solution over the interval $[0,10]$

Find the two first digits of one of the solution using the bisection method.

I started with defining $f(x)=ln(x^2+2x+\frac{1}{2})-x=0$

I checked the points: $x=0, x=10$

$f(0) = ln(\frac{1}{2}) < 0$

$f(10) = ln(120.5) - 10 < 0$

So according to the intermediate value theorem if I find $f(c) > 0$ in the range $[0,10]$ there should be 2 solutions, right?

So: $f(1) = ln(3.5) - 1 > 0$, so indeed the function has 2 solutions.

I'm not sure about my solution, is this the right approach by far? 
Furthermore, how do I find the solution using the bisection method? I do I apply it here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof that there are two solutions is correct (if you remember to argue that you can use the mean value theorem.

From your calculations you know that one of the solutions are in the interval $[0,1]$, use the bisection methos on that.